# Match and replace values from one dataframe with another

Tags: r, loops

Let's say I have two dataframes like below, (real dataset has many more rows and cols)

```
df = data.frame("Worker" = c("JBB","JDD","MB","JBB"),
                 "Age" = c(4,5,6,4))

df2 = data.frame("Initials" = c("JBB","JDD","MB","JOD"),
                 "Worker" = c("Joe Bloggs/JBB", "Jane Doe/JDD", 
                                "Mr. Big/MB", "John Doe/JOD"))
```

I would like to replace the `Worker` col in `df` with the `Worker` col from `df2`
In the future more workers will be added to both dataframes so it would be nice if there was a quick and easy way to do this rather than manually doing something like this for each set of initials

```
df$Worker<-paste(gsub("JBB", "Joe Bloggs/JBB", df$Worker, perl=TRUE))
```

Perhaps a loop or simply some kind of `tidyverse::replace` solution

I have tried various `joins` but they don't work for me.

Have also tried

```
df %>%
mutate(new_Worker = case_when(df$Worker == df2$Initials ~ df2$Worker)
```

This gives errors too.

Comment: My suggestion is to separate the initials from the actual name and use that for the join since df1 has initials I presume ie replace everything before `/` and join.

Comment: Hi @NelsonGon, joins don't really do what I want. I need the "full name/initials" part of the second df added to the first one. Something like ```tidyverse::case_when``` but I just can't figure out the logic and how best to implement in an efficient way, have edited question to reflect trying with joins

Comment: What is wrong with this approach `df %>% 
  rename(Initials = Worker) %>% 
  left_join(df2)`

Comment: Yes @MohanGovindasamy, this does in fact also work. If you see below I had some errant whitespace which I hadn't picked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

inner_join(df, df2, by = c("Worker" = "Initials"))

#>   Worker Age       Worker.y
#> 1    JBB   4 Joe Bloggs/JBB
#> 2    JDD   5   Jane Doe/JDD
#> 3     MB   6     Mr. Big/MB
#> 4    JBB   4 Joe Bloggs/JBB
```

Comment: So this works on the dummy dataset provided but not on the larger one? Can't figure why, I just get an empty dataframe??

Comment: Without the true data, it is hard to figure out the reason behind that...

Comment: Sorry it works, there was an extra bit of whitespace in the dataframe! d'oh

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to rename the `Worker` column in `df` as you do the join

```
left_join(rename(df, Initials = Worker), 
          df2)
```

this results in the `data.frame` with columns 'Initials', 'Worker' and 'Age'. It also assumes that `df` is the data and that `df2` is the lookup list.

I don't think you would use `case_when` for this example. Presumably there is a large number of Initials.

The other option is to `filter` and `pull` the values from df2.

```
df |>
  mutate(Worker = map_chr(Worker, 
                          ~ filter(df2, Initials == .x) |>  
                                   pull(Worker)
                          )
         )
```

The `map_chr` above is needed otherwise the nested filter does not work